# How to solve the error from read_docx when exporting a flextable to word

Tags: r, flextable, officer

I kept on receiving the error message when trying to export the flextable to word document.

Example:

> doc <- read_docx()
>   *Error in utils::unzip(file, exdir = tmp) : 
>     argument "file" is missing, with no default*
>   doc <- body_add_flextable(doc,value=t13,align = "center",split = TRUE)
>   *Error in inherits(x, "rdocx") : object 'doc' not found*
>   print(doc,target = "Table13.docx")
>   *Error in print(doc, target = "Table13.docx") : object 'doc' not found*

Among all the errors returned, it seems read_docx() function is not applied correctly.  I have no idea how to fix it.  Anyone has any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Could be one of  problems:
1. the function read_docx maybe overwritten by another package. Does it work if you do `doc <- officer::read_docx()`
2. Or a rights issue. When I look at read_docx, it looks like it creates a temporary empty document, and then reads that. If it cannot read that temporary file, an error occurs.

Comment: If you execute `doc<-read_docx()` again and then immediately type `traceback()`, what do you get? It tells you where exactly the error occurs.

Comment: Hi Emil@Emil Bode, thank you for the solution!  doc <- officer::read_docx() really works! Also, as you suggested, I executed doc <- read_docx(), and type traceback(), what I got is : > doc<-read_docx()
Error in utils::unzip(file, exdir = tmp) : 
  argument "file" is missing, with no default
> traceback()
2: utils::unzip(file, exdir = tmp)
1: read_docx() looks like the read_docx maybe overwritten by another package.

Comment: BTW, if you want to know which package is overwriting it, you can use `getAnywhere('read_docx')`, this will give you extensive information of which objects there are out there under that name.

Comment: And if you get tired of typing `officer::read_docx` all the time, you can reassign it in your global environment: `read_docx <- officer::read_docx`. Then it's the first item to be found.

Comment: thanks! they are really helpful.@Emil Bode